# Stuck on Maze H.W, info inside. please Assembly emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

http://jbwyatt.com/253/a/a5Mazes.htm

thats a link to my homework.

i have the maze drawn out, and the ending and starting point
what confuses me is how to get started on the other tasks.
i normally pick up on programming languages right away but assembly to me is a giant headache.

if someone can give me a few examples and point me in the right direction i should be able to get over the speedbump and hit the gas.

```
INCLUDE "emu8086.inc"
ORG 100h

; LINE 1 -------------
lea si, maz1
mov cx, 20
wall1:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p1
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx1
p1:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx1: inc si
loop wall1
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 2 -------------
lea si, maz2
mov cx, 20
wall2:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p2
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx2
p2:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx2: inc si
loop wall2
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 3 -------------
lea si, maz3
mov cx, 20
wall3:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p3
     PUTC    219       ; white block:
     jmp nx3
p3:  PUTC    32        ; blank space
nx3: inc si
loop wall3
PRINTN ;****


; LINE 4 -------------
lea si, maz4
mov cx, 20
wall4:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p4
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx4
p4:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx4: inc si
loop wall4
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 5 -------------
lea si, maz5
mov cx, 20
wall5:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p5
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx5
p5:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx5: inc si
loop wall5
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 6 -------------
lea si, maz6
mov cx, 20
wall6:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p6
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx6
p6:  PUTC    32        ; blank space
nx6: inc si
loop wall6
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 7 -------------
lea si, maz7
mov cx, 20
wall7:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p7
     PUTC    219       ; white block:
     jmp nx7
p7:  PUTC    32        ;   blank space
nx7: inc si
loop wall7
PRINTN ;****


; LINE 8 -------------
lea si, maz8
mov cx, 20
wall8:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p8
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx8
p8:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx8: inc si
loop wall8
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 9 -------------
lea si, maz9
mov cx, 20
wall9:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p9
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx9
p9:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx9: inc si
loop wall9
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 10 -------------
lea si, maz10
mov cx, 20
wall10:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p10
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx10
p10:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx10: inc si
loop wall10
PRINTN ;****

; LINEW 11 -------------
lea si, maz11
mov cx, 20
wall11:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p11
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx11
p11:  PUTC    32        ;   blank space
nx11: inc si
loop wall11
PRINTN ;****


; LINE 12 -------------
lea si, maz12
mov cx, 20
wall12:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p12
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx12
p12:  PUTC    32        ;   blank space
nx12: inc si
loop wall12
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 13 -------------
lea si, maz13
mov cx, 20
wall13:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p13
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx13
p13:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx13: inc si
loop wall13
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 14 -------------
lea si, maz14
mov cx, 20
wall14:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p14
     PUTC    219       ; white block:
     jmp nx14
p14:  PUTC    32        ; blank space
nx14: inc si
loop wall14
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 15 -------------
lea si, maz15
mov cx, 20
wall15:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p15
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx15
p15:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx15: inc si
loop wall15
PRINTN ;****


; LINE 16 -------------
lea si, maz16
mov cx, 20
wall16:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p16
     PUTC    219       ; white block:
     jmp nx16
p16:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx16: inc si
loop wall16
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 17 -------------
lea si, maz17
mov cx, 20
wall17:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p17
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx17
p17:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx17: inc si
loop wall17
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 18 -------------
lea si, maz18
mov cx, 20
wall18:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p18
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx18
p18:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx18: inc si
loop wall18
PRINTN ;****

; LINE 19 -------------
lea si, maz19
mov cx, 20
wall19:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p19
     PUTC    219       ;  white block:
     jmp nx19
p19:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx19: inc si
loop wall19
PRINTN ;****


; LINE 20 -------------
lea si, maz20
mov cx, 20
wall20:
     cmp [si], 0 ; path
     je p20
     PUTC    219       ; white block:
     jmp nx20
p20:  PUTC    32        ;  blank space
nx20: inc si
loop wall20
PRINTN ;****




; PUT GUY AND END IN MAZE
GOTOXY 1, 1       ;guy at start position
PUTC 01

GOTOXY 18, 17     ;finish point
PUTC 03         
ret

  maz1  DB  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
  maz2  DB  1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1
  maz3  DB  1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1
  maz4  DB  1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1
  maz5  DB  1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1
  maz6  DB  1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1
  maz7  DB  1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
  maz8  DB  1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1
  maz9  DB  1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1
  maz10 DB  1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1
  maz11 DB  1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
  maz12 DB  1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1
  maz13 DB  1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1
  maz14 DB  1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1
  maz15 DB  1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1
  maz16 DB  1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1
  maz17 DB  1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1
  maz18 DB  1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1
  maz19 DB  1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,3,1
  maz20 DB  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to do it in a language you know better? Then make a plan of how you would. Then try to convert that plan into assembly, piece by piece. Then if you have more specific problems you will find it easier to get answers.

Comment: i took java, i took c++, C#.. 

i guess you're right, 
but at the same time i feel like i am atleast somewhere with this one already.

Answer (score 0):

*****Define your maze in one single array, not 20.

*****You don't want to print it line by line... Make a loop.

*****Character moves with wasd:

W = char position - 20 (check if maze[pos-20] != 1 or == endpoint)

A = char position - 1

D = char position + 1

S = char position + 20

Those are the problems I saw in the code above.

Where else do you have problems? Anything specific you don't know how to do?

1- Make 1 array for the maze and print it on screen with a loop.

2- Get input and move the character with wasd by addind/substracting 1 and 20 while checking for walls and endpoint

3- I don't how the graphic part of this homework can be implemented in this language. I did make a maze game but it was for a debugging contest. (map in memory, not on the screen) So I can help with the logic if you update your code a little.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

1)i'm not sure how i would read in WADS characters and loop the maze.
i've been looking back and forth on it trying to figure it out.

2) what you're saying is i can take the 20 line sections out and just have one line section instead?





3- i also felt like the graphic part couldn't be implemented.